# what is this error while creating project in android studio I can't understand

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.c[enter image description here][1]om/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: you have diffrent version of dependency  in library or your poroject

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a different version that will result to this problem
this is mentioned in gradle.
 so just use the same version and your problem will solved.
 and if the problem is not solved then upload your gradle dependencies to see and check that